# How array push in a called function updates the array in caller function , which is passed to a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In `Javascript` when we pass a local array defined in a function to a different function as an argument it will modify the array upstream **unless the array is Empty**
For example say `foo` to a different function say `bar`

```
var foo = function() { 
  var x = [9];  //Array is not empty
  bar(x);
  console.log("x =>",x);
}; 
var bar = function(x) {x[0] = 1;};
foo(); // x => [1]
```

the output of `x => [1]`, and if the array empty and modified in the called function `bar` it does not updates the array in the caller function `foo`

```
var foo = function(){ 
  var x = []; //Array is empty
  bar(x); 
  console.log("x =>",x); }; 
var bar = function(x) {x = [1];};
foo(); // x => []
```

But in case if we use array push why, how it updates the empty array in `foo`?

```
var foo = function(){ var x = []; bar(x); console.log("x =>",x); }; 
var bar = function(x) {x.push(3);};
foo(); // x => [3]
```

Comment: Because you're calling `push` on the array reference. In the first example you're setting `x`, but it's a different `x` because it's inside a function.

Comment: There is no special rule about empty arrays behaving differently, and your first example should print `[9]`. (Just in case, verified it in FF20). If you tried to simplify your actual problem into minimal piece of code, you must have had omitted something important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `bar`, `x = [1]` simply assigns a **new value** to the variable `x`. The variable is local to the function and this has no impact on the variable you used to pass the argument (imagine you hadn't used a variable to pass the value, but a literal, like `bar([1,2]);`).

`x.push(3)` on the other hand does **not** assign a new value. It modifies the array in-place. This works because arrays are mutable.

Similarly, `x[0] = 1;` changes the array *in-place*, by assigning a new value to the first position of the array.

Much simpler example:

```
var foo = [1];
var bar = foo;

bar.push(2);
console.log(foo); // shows [1, 2]

bar = 42;
console.log(foo); // still shows [1, 2]
```

`foo` and `bar` reference the same array at the beginning, hence you can modify the array with either variable. Later we assign a new value to `bar`. This has no impact on the value of `foo`, it still references the array.

Whether or not you pass the values to a function does not make a difference.

---

As already pointed out, there is no difference between empty or non-empty arrays. The result you claim to get for the first example is incorrect. The output will be `[9]`.

Comment: In short, you have a reference to an array `bar`, making the reference equal something entirely different doesn't affect the original reference of `foo`. Pretty consistent behavior across languages.

Comment: @FeistyMango the result in the first example is right, and I tested it in Chrome.

Comment: @Akinza Oh I know it's right =P Thus the upvote haha. I was just offering a shortened perspective on his answer.

Comment: @Felix you were right about the first example I edited, and in second example I am re-assigning `x` with an array `[1]`, which is no more pointing to the empty array in `foo`

Comment: @Akinza: That makes more sense now. I updated my answer, but I assume you already understood why you get the result in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

In both the 2nd and 3rd examples, `x` is a variable which contains a reference to the in-memory Array object.

In the second example, `bar` reassigns the variable `x` to a new Array object, namely `[1]`.  This has no effect on the original in-memory Array object.  All you have done is re-assigned a variable.

In the 3rd example, you call `x.push`: This calls the push method on the Array object referenced by the variable "x", and thus changes that array.

The key concepts here are:

1. The difference between a variable and the object it refers to.  The same variable will point to a new object if you reassign it.
2. In javascript, when you call a function and pass in an object, you are passing a reference to that object, and anything you do to it will affect the original object.

As Felix noted, the first example behaves the same as the 2nd.